# Выборка из одной таблицы по условию (where) из нескольких

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица **users**, в ней хранятся `user_id`, `username`, `email` и другая информация.

Есть таблица **user_last_logins**, в которой поля `user_id`, `last_login`.

Есть таблица **user_configs** с полем `user_id` и остальными.

Требуется сделать выборку (уникальных по `user_id`) записей из **users**, но в качестве условия использовать данные из других таблиц.

```
SELECT * from users where ( 
   (users.user_name != "") **AND** 
   (Если у этого user_id в таблице user_last_logins last_login > 0) **AND** 
   (Если для этого user_id существует запись в таблице user_configs) 
) group by users.user_id
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: посмотрите условие `exists` -если я правильно понял,  это как раз, что вам надо

Comment: если я правильно понял, то нужно сначала почитать книжку про sql, а не браться сразу за дело, которого не знаешь, чтобы потом канючить  по разным форумам.Понимание SQL Мартина, как там его... Грубера, например. Там найдёте как решить свою проблему.

Comment: @Sergey, вы поняли правильно, но задача требует решения сейчас, а книжки будет время почитать потом

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, мне не трудно разобраться, как проверить существование записи, я просто описал запрос человеческим языком.
У меня главная запара - это как использовать в качестве условия данные из нескольких таблиц

Comment: @Robert выложите на sqlfiddle.com структуру и тестовые данные. будет проще вам помочь

Comment: @splash58, большое вам спасибо за попытку помощи, разобрался сам :)

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, помогло выражение типа:

LEFT JOIN user_last_logins ON (users.user_id = user_last_logins.user_id)

и далее уже WHERE какое нужно